# parsing conditional operators as strings and using as conditional operators

Tags: string, perl, operators

```
my $line ="Corner:Default,Output:fall_delay_slew_1,Mean=34.97p,Std-      dev=1.767p,Min=30.02p,Max=39.71p";    #added semicolon
my $my_value="COND = Mean > 3"; #this has come from the parsed file.
$my_value =~ m/(\w+)\s*(.)\s*(\d+)/;
my $cond=$1;
my $sign=$2;
my $value=$3;
print "DEBUG:cond is $cond and sign $sign and value $value \n";
if ( $line =~ m/$cond=(.*?),/) {
if ( "$value $sign $1" ) {
    print "$value is $sign than $1\n";
} else {
    print "actual value is less\n";
 }
}
```

If you see in the above if statement always evaluates to true.

How can I solve this kind of problem i.e `$sign = "<"` (could be any operator)
but when I want to compare it with `$value` I want it to function as an
operator and not as a string.

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're willing to do (executing a  string as code) can be done with
[`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html). That doesn't  mean it is the most appropriate  way of doing
it though. Do it  only if you guarantee your input  safety and check for
it.

A better  way would be checking  the operator your self  and determining
how to proceed. If you use  a recent Perl version, the [`given-when`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements)
feature can be handy to do this:

```
use feature 'switch'; # not needed if you already use 5.010 or greater

given ($sign) {
    when ('<') { say "$cond less than $value" }
    when ('>') { say "$cond greater than $value" }
    default {
        warn "unrecognized operator `$sign'\n";
        # decide what to do
    }
}
```

Comment: To the down voter, I must say that I will be pleased to make corrections to this answer as soon as the reasons for the negative rating are known to me. And apologies in advance if I overlooked something.